# Strange behavior of HRTBs

Tags: rust

[I have this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=facd67a79da916192e7970070de9db1a&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

struct S<A>
where
    for<'a> A: Debug + 'a,
{
    f: Box<Fn(A) -> i32>,
}

impl<A> S<A>
where
    for<'a> A: Debug + 'a,
{
    fn call(&self, a: A) {
        println!("Return {:?}", (self.f)(a));
    }
}

fn create<A>(f: Box<Fn(A) -> i32>) -> S<A>
where
    for<'a> A: Debug + 'a,
{
    S::<A> { f }
}

fn helper() {
    let x = create::<&i32>(Box::new(|x: &i32| *x * 2));
    let arg = 333;
    x.call(&arg);
}

fn main() {
    let x = helper();
}
```

It's failed to compile:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `A` may not live long enough
```

In [code 2](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f45d112650a4f039cf57d6450e87289f&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015), I changed `Fn(A) -> i32` to `Fn(&A) -> i32`, the code works.

```
...
    f: Box<Fn(&A) -> i32>,
...
```

Since `A` is argument of `Fn` trait, it's a type that has `Higher-Rank lifetime`. It shouldn't be affected by the lifetime of struct `S<A>` .

But why can't code 1 be compiled?
How can I workaround it for borrow or non-borrow type `A`?

Comment: I think it's because nothing prevent A to be a reference.

Comment: I believe I have seen this before, as a compiler bug.  

`for<'a> A: Debug + 'a` is (roughly) sugar for `A: for<'a> Debug + for<'a> 'a`, but the latter doesn't parse, and I doubt the former should either.  

It's possible the lifetime (name) resolution, and/or something down the line, doesn't see the bound properly - and quite likely that it's unaccounted for.  

I'll update this comment after I hear back from @nikomatsakis or some other compiler developer.

Comment: Even after reading eddyb's answer, I'm not sure what you want `for<'a> A: Debug + 'a` to mean. It just looks like a funny way of writing `A: Debug + 'static` to me.

Comment: @trentcl ``A: Debug + 'static`` doesn't work when `A` is borrowing type

Comment: ... neither does `for<'a> A: Debug + 'a` because you can instantiate `'a = 'static`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no easy way to make `helper` work in current Rust, even if you remove all the `for<'a> A: Debug + 'a,` bounds (which only *further restricts* what types `A` can be, whereas you want to *allow more*).

This is as simple as I can make your example:

```
struct S<A> {
    f: Box<Fn(A) -> i32>,
}

impl<A> S<A> {
    fn call(&self, a: A) {
        println!("Return {:?}", (self.f)(a));
    }
}

fn create<A>(f: Box<Fn(A) -> i32>) -> S<A> {
    S { f }
}

fn helper() {
    let x = create(Box::new(|x: &i32| *x * 2));
    let arg = 333;
    x.call(&arg);
}

fn main() {
    helper();
}
```

The reason it doesn't work is that `A` "comes from the outside", and Rust can't infer that you want `for<'a> S<&'a A>`, it can't even talk about such a type.
Note that if `let arg = 333;` is placed above `let x`, this example *does compile* (because it infers a reference to `arg` *specifically*, not a `for<'a>`).

The closest you can get today is with an associated type on a trait with a lifetime parameter, e.g.:

```
// Emulating `type Type<'a>` by moving `'a` to the trait.
trait Apply<'a> {
    type Type;
}
struct Plain<T>(std::marker::PhantomData<T>);
impl<'a, T> Apply<'a> for Plain<T> {
    type Type = T;
}
struct Ref<T: ?Sized>(std::marker::PhantomData<T>);
impl<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> Apply<'a> for Ref<T> {
    type Type = &'a T;
}

struct S<A: for<'a> Apply<'a>> {
    f: Box<for<'a> Fn(<A as Apply<'a>>::Type) -> i32>,
}

impl<A: for<'a> Apply<'a>> S<A> {
    fn call<'a>(&self, a: <A as Apply<'a>>::Type) {
        println!("Return {:?}", (self.f)(a));
    }
}

fn create<A: for<'a> Apply<'a>>(
    f: Box<for<'a> Fn(<A as Apply<'a>>::Type) -> i32>,
) -> S<A> {
    S { f }
}

fn helper() {
    let x = create::<Ref<i32>>(Box::new(|x: &i32| *x * 2));
    let arg = 333;
    x.call(&arg);
}

fn main() {
    helper();
}
```

However, it turns out that this encoding hits https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52812, so it's not actually usable at the moment (and I'm not aware of an workaround).